# Django QS filter by nested annotated field

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two `Django` models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...


class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now I want to add filtering `Book`s by their `author`'s full name (`first_name` + `last_name`). I've added `FilterSet` with following logic:

```py
qs_prefetched = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("authors", User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')))
).all().filter(authors__full_name__icontains=value)
```

And when I try to filter in that way I have following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: full_name
```

But field `full_name` is in `authors` values:

```sh
(Pdb) qs_prefetched[1].authors.all()[0].full_name
'Ke Xu'
```

Can anybody tell what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotation is on the prefetched queryset. You need to annotate the base queryset as well in order to filter it as desired.

Something like this:

```
qs_prefetched = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("authors", User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')))
).annotate(
    calc_full_name=Concat('authors__first_name', Value(' '), 'authors__last_name')
).filter(calc_full_name__icontains=value)
```

Though admittedly, I skeptical if above will work as exactly as you want because it's trying to annotate across a many to many relationship.

Another option would be to use a [Subquery and Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) filter in which you look up the users who match the name, the filter on an exists check.

```
user_subquery = User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name').filter(
    full_name__icontains=value,
    id=OuterRef('author_id'), # This depends on your models.
)
qs_prefetched = queryset.filter(Exists(user_subquery)).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("authors", User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')))
)
```

Comment: First approach doesn't work, `annotate` only concat only fields from first object from M2M.

But second one works fine. Didn't thought about filtering Users and then use `Subquery` and `Exists`.